# how does this break the watching value?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.$watch('num',function(){
  $scope.nums.push($scope.num)
})
```

Changing the above code breaks the watching value on clicked (I'm unclear because breakit still pushing the value to nums):

```
$scope.breakit = $scope.$watch('num',function(){
  $scope.nums.push($scope.num)
})
```

But I'm unclear how does this break the watching value?

Full code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
   <div>Num: {{num}}</div>
   <div>Nums: {{nums}}</div>
   <button ng-click="increment()">Increment</button>
   <button ng-click="breakit()">Break It</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
   $scope.num = 0
   $scope.nums = []
   $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.num++;
   }
   $scope.breakit = $scope.$watch('num',function(){
      $scope.nums.push($scope.num)
   })
});
```

So, using `$scope.breakit` why does this stops pushing the `num` to `nums` clicking to break it button and continue clicking to increment button?

You may check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5Kbt8LOb_8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for `$scope.watch()` says:

> Returns
>
> function() Returns a deregistration function for this listener

When you call `$scope.watch()`, it returns a function that you can call at any time to unregister it.

Your controller assigns that function to `$scope.breakit`, so when `$scope.breakit` is called, the watch is turned off.

---

**Edit:**

There was a question in the comments about how `$scope.break` pushes values to the `nums` array. The answer is that it doesn't. `$scope.watch()` takes care of that all on its own, and `$scope.break` is used as a way to turn that process off.

Comment: Did you try just plain:
$scope.$watch('num',function(){
      $scope.numbs.push($scope.num)
   });

instead of assigning it another variable. BTW your syntax is fine for this operation except for assigning $watch to another scope var

Comment: ummm, but the code i.e. pushing the value inside $scope.break... sorry, but unclear with this.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal No, in the code, values are pushed to `$scope.nums` in the ___callback function___ that is passed into `$scope.watch()`. The ___return value___ of `$scope.watch()` is assigned to `$scope.break`. `$scope.break` is responsible for **stopping** the watch, not carrying it out. `$scope.watch()` will behave the way it does whether you use its return value or not. Using its return value simply provides a way to stop it.